# Deleting Everything After a Character with Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
Charlie Wilson's War
<span class="nobr">(<a href="/year/2007/">2007</a>)</span>
```

For my stuff above, I can't figure out a Javascript Regex pattern to delete < and everything after so I can get only the title. This must be easy.

Comment: are you trying to keep only the text part and removing the html?

Comment: So, he thought "I know, I will use a regular expression!" .. the moral of the story is: their are now two problems. Instead of asking "how can I do this with a regular expression", consider asking "how can I [do this task]"? Depending upon the source there are likely better and more reliable methods.

Comment: `var title = markup.split('<')[0];`

Comment: @antisanity has nice solution, but if you desperately want Regex.. then you can try the following, where you will replace whatever matches the Regex `\s<.*` with nothing i.e. `''` and you will get the title

Comment: @ufuk-sarp-selcok glad it helped, will still ask you to go with antisanity solution for reference you can learn the pattern....

Comment: @UfukSarpSelçok: Are you by any chance getting that string from an innerHTML call or similar? If so, it might be safer to use DOM manipulation methods to get at the title directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = 'Charlie Wilson\'s War<span class="nobr">...</span>';
console.log(html.split('<')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A regexp pattern could be `[^<]+`, therefore:

```
var string = "Charlie Wilson's War<span class=\"nobr\">(<a href=\"/year/2007/\">2007</a>)</span>";

var re = /[^<]+/;

console.log(string.match(re));
```