# How to replace everything after first instance of character in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I want to remove everything except the words before the first comma in a string containing several comma-delimited values:

ie - Value One, Value Two, Value Three, Value Four

I am looking to isolate only "Value One" and return it.  The values are different across several strings with the same format, so I want to replace based on the first comma as opposed to replacing specific values.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using/open to using any libraries or is this some kind of academic exercise?

Comment: Duplicate of [Remove everything after a certain character](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5631384/), [remove everything after and including certain character](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6873720/), [Deleting Everything After a Character with Javascript Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11316557/) and probably many others.

Answer (score 5):

```
var string = 'Value One, Value Two, Value Three, Value Four';

string = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(','));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2PJCe/

Comment: You beat me by few seconds. This is the best solution IMO, +1!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
var stuff = "Value One, Value Two, Value Three, Value Four";
var first = stuff.split(",")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the result.

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";//your string
var result = str.substring(0,str.indexOf(","));//result
```

Comment: Dupe! Check Xander's answer

Comment: I did not see that he has already replied. While I started writing, no answer was there. He beat me by 12 seconds.

Comment: It can happen when answering these simple questions

Comment: Yes. Will take care from next time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using regex:

```
var string = "Value One, Value Two, Value Three, Value Four";
var first = string.replace(/,.*/s, "");
```